# In Javascript, how to start a server-side process and monitor its output until completion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

In my web application I'd like to be able to start a process with certain parameters on the web server, and continuously display output from the process in a text area until it completes. How can I accomplish this with Javascript? I'm using jQuery along with ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: You can't accomplish this with "javascript" it's done with HTTP.

Comment: @Raynos Do you suggest I perform dynamic updates in the client view with HTTP? :P

Comment: you make HTTP requests to a server to start the process, then make further HTTP requests to extract data. You can render it however you want.

Comment: @Raynos It was a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use some of the new stuff coming out.  For details see:

[SignalR according to Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20ScottHanselman%20%28Scott%20Hanselman%20-%20ComputerZen.com%29&utm_content=My%20Yahoo)

[Node.js according to Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx)

Having said that, it is all new, and still under development I understand.  But it looks like the way this kind of development is going.

Comment: SignalR is a Comet implementation for ASP.NET MVC am I right? What would Node.js give me in my case, I've only sussed out so far that it lets you execute Javascript on the server-side?

Comment: I *think* it allows signalR to run, but I'm still reading up myself, no expert.  Sorry.  It does sound like what you need tho...

Comment: It does look like a better alternative to Ajax, so thanks! I think I'll have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: SignalR appears to enable me to start tasks on the server and receive updates, so I'll accept this answer so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with 2 action methods and a javascript timer

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult StartProcess()
{
    StartTheMachine();
    return new JsonResult() { Data = "Started" };
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetProcessUpdate()
{
    return new JsonResult() 
    {
        Data = GetUpdate(), 
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet 
    };
}
```

and in your view something like this:

```
$.post("<%=Url.Action("StartProcess") %>", function(data) {
    // do something with data "Started" and start timer
    setTimeout(GetUpdate, 5000);
});

function GetUpdate()
{
    $.get("<%=Url.Action("GetUpdate") %>", function(data) {
        if (data.Complete) // or some way to tell it has finished
        {
            // do something with other data returned
        }
        else
        {
            // call again if not finished
            setTimeout(GetUpdate, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to send a ajax post(or get) in regular time intervals to server side and get the process status.

```
$.get("controler/ActionToReturnStatusView", null,
   function(data){
     alert("status " + data);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

can use comet programming.
can try web workers supported in HTML 5

Comment: Ah, I'd forgot about web workers. Thanks, might be worth looking into. I hear from a friend that Comet is the way to go these days.